# Control Notification "Show Previews" option programmatically on iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I need to set my app Notification "Show Previews" options to "When Unlocked (Default)". How can we configure it using the UNNotificationSettings? I do not see an option to configure it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not do this because these settings can not be changeable by 
code. Push-notifications will display according to the settings set by user for his/her device.

Comment: Can we change notification title or body text when show preview is selected never or off? For now I have selected never and I am getting title as "Notification".